# QtCreator: pure virtual method called terminate called withouth an active exception

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

Este error me sale cando intento mandar a llamar a la camara uEye en mi programa en Qtcreator, se me hace raro ya que antes nunca me marco este tipo de error y no estoy seguro de que deberia cambiar, este es el codigo donde mando llamar a la camara

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_14_clicked()
{
        ui->label->clear();
        HIDS hCam = 0;
        SENSORINFO sInfo;
        HWND hWndDisplay;

        char* pcImageMemory;
        int DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight;
           is_InitCamera(&hCam, hWndDisplay);
            // You can query information about the sensor type used in the camera
            is_GetSensorInfo(hCam, &sInfo);

            // Saving the information about the max. image proportions in variables
            DisplayWidth = sInfo.nMaxWidth;
            DisplayHeight = sInfo.nMaxHeight;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // Need to find out the memory size of the pixel and the colour mode
            int nColorMode;
            int nBitsPerPixel = 24;

            if (sInfo.nColorMode == IS_COLORMODE_BAYER)
            {
                // For color camera models use RGB24 mode
                nColorMode = IS_CM_BGR8_PACKED;
                nBitsPerPixel = 24;
            }
            else if (sInfo.nColorMode == IS_COLORMODE_CBYCRY)
            {
                // For CBYCRY camera models use RGB32 mode
                nColorMode = IS_CM_BGRA8_PACKED;
                nBitsPerPixel = 32;
            }
            else
            {
                // For monochrome camera models use Y8 mode
                nColorMode = IS_CM_MONO16;
                nBitsPerPixel = 24;
            }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            int nMemoryId;

            // Assigns a memory for the image and sets it active
            is_AllocImageMem(hCam, DisplayWidth, DisplayHeight, nBitsPerPixel, &pcImageMemory, &nMemoryId);
            is_SetImageMem(hCam, pcImageMemory, nMemoryId);



            // Acquires a single image from the camera
            is_FreezeVideo(hCam, IS_WAIT);
            int t = 1;
            // Parameter definition for saving the image file
            IMAGE_FILE_PARAMS ImageFileParams;
            QString Q1 = "/home/pi/Pictures/SimpleImage";
            QString Dir = "";
            QString Num = QString::number(t);
            QString Q2 = ".bmp";
            QString Total = Q1 + Num + Q2;
            qDebug() << Total;
            wchar_t *Array = new wchar_t[Total.length() + 1];

            Total.toWCharArray(Array);
            Array[Total.length()] = 0;
            qDebug() << Total;

            //ImageFileParams.pwchFileName =  "/home/pi/prueba.png";//L"/home/pi/Pictures/TestImage1"<< (wchar_t*)t<< L".bmp";   // <-- Insert name and location of the image
            ImageFileParams.pwchFileName = Array;
            ImageFileParams.pnImageID = NULL;
            ImageFileParams.ppcImageMem = NULL;
            ImageFileParams.nQuality = 0;
            ImageFileParams.nFileType = IS_IMG_BMP;

            // Saves the image file
            if (is_ImageFile(hCam, IS_IMAGE_FILE_CMD_SAVE, (void*)&ImageFileParams, sizeof(ImageFileParams)) == IS_SUCCESS)
            {
                qDebug() <<"An Image was saved";
            }
            else
            {
                qDebug() <<"something went wrong";
            }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            // Releases an image memory that was allocated
            is_FreeImageMem(hCam, pcImageMemory, nMemoryId);


        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            QPixmap pixmap(Total);
            ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);

               ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
               QApplication::processEvents();

            delete[] Array;


            // Disables the hCam camera handle and releases the data structures and memory areas taken up by the uEye camera
            is_ExitCamera(hCam);
            //digitalWrite(3,LOW);

}
```

Mucha parte de este codigo es el que viene en la paguina de iDS uEye para capturar un frame desde la camara

Comment: Este error se suele deber a un doble `delete`. Es decir, dos objetos diferentes piensan o asumen que deben gestionar el ciclo de vida de un objeto común. El primero borra el objeto correctamente, pero el segundo se encuentra con un objeto ya borrado y cuya tabla de funciones virtuales ya no es válida. Con el código que muestras es complicado darte una respuesta mejor... prueba a ir deshabilitando partes del código para ir acotando el problema.

Comment: ¿Dónde exactamente de las decenas de líneas que has compartido te salta el error?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster No hay exacamente un una linea de error porque no me marca que este mal simplemente es el mensaje que me arroja, estoy suponiendo que es la parte cuando entra a la camara

Comment: @Dohko19 eso complica mucho las cosas :'( tanto para ti como para los que queramos ayudarte.